# Testing web applications in go

Tags: authentication, go, testing, web-applications

I am following Alex Edwards' Let's Go and have been trying to unit test handlers. One thing I am stuck on is that I am unable to properly test endpoints that can only be accessed through authentication; atleast in a clean manner.

Since I am using the scs as my session manager, I am unable to think of way to integrate into the same methodology proposed by the book. The book proposes the following test helpers to call upon from unit tests.

`func newTestApplication(t *testing.T) *application which sets the sessionManager, logs and models,etc.`

`func newTestServer(t *testing.T, h http.Handler) *testServer sets up the testserver`

`func (ts *testServer) get(t *testing.T, urlPath string) (int, http.Header, string) handles get methods`

Suppose HandlerA can only be accessed by authenticated users;

```
TestHandlerA{

app := newTestApplication(t)

ts := newTestServer(t, app.routes())

defer ts.Close()
//test cases 

for _, tt := range tests{
    t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T){
           ts.get(t, tt.urlPath)
//assertions
     })
}`
```

I want to be able to give the authenticated user's id and then test
Any suggestions?

Info:
I add a request context of the authenticated user id to the session manager when the user logs in. The session manager loads and saves and the request is carried through a middleware which checks if the user is authenticated and then allows the user to access restricted endpoints.

Moreover I would love to know other patterns people use for testing endpoints behind restricted behind authentication/authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Testing authenticated routes can be tricky and here are some strategies I would use:

**Mock Authentication**
In your test setup, you could mock the authentication mechanism to simulate a user being logged in. Essentially, you would bypass the actual authentication process and insert a simulated user into the session.

For example, you might update your newTestApplication(t *testing.T) function to allow inserting a mock authenticated user into the session:

```
   func newTestApplication(t *testing.T, mockUserID string) *application {
    // your code

    // mock the session if mockUserID is set
    if mockUserID != "" {
        app.sessionManager.Put(r.Context(), "authenticatedUserID", mockUserID)
    }
    return app
}
```

**Directly Set Session**
Since you are using SCS for session management, you can directly interact with the session during your tests to set the user as authenticated:

```
    func setSessionAuthenticated(session *scs.SessionManager, userID string) {
    // You would typically set this in your middleware
    session.Put(context.Background(), "authenticatedUserID", userID)
}
```

You would call this in your test setup after creating your test application and before making any requests to the authenticated routes:

```
    tests := []struct {
    name        string
    urlPath     string
    mockUserID  string
    wantStatus  int
    // ... other fields
}{
    {"Unauthorized", "/restricted", "", http.StatusUnauthorized},
    {"Authorized", "/restricted", "mockUserID", http.StatusOK},
    // ... other test cases
}

for _, tt := range tests {
    t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
        app := newTestApplication(t, tt.mockUserID)
        ts := newTestServer(t, app.routes())
        defer ts.Close()

        status, _, _ := ts.get(t, tt.urlPath)
        
        if status != tt.wantStatus {
            t.Errorf("want %d; got %d", tt.wantStatus, status)
        }

        // ... other assertions
    })
}
```

Try to combine these strategies, it was helpful to me.

Cheers....

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had initially tried your suggestions but I cannot implement it without changing the structure. newTestApplication() does not have any assignment associated with the http package itself and my middleware only processes requests and not sets the authentication of the session. I do that in my login handler. 
i.e;
the equivalent to this app.sessionManager.Put(r.Context(), "authenticatedUserID",userID) can be found there.

Answer (score 0):

My approach was to create a mockAuthentication middleware that assigns an authenticatedUserID in to the session manager before calling the real authentication middleware. It looks like this:

```
func (app *application) mockAuthentication(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        app.sessionManager.Put(r.Context(), "authenticatedUserID", userID)
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Now, when we create a test server for testing the particular handler that requires authentication, we can pass app.routes() wrapped in our mockAuthentication middleware, hence, passing the authenticatedUserID to our real authentication middlewares down the call stack.

```
func TestHandler(t *testing.T) {
    app := newTestApplication(t)
    ts := newTestServer(t, app.sessionManager.LoadAndSave(app.mockAuthentication(app.routes())))
    defer ts.Close()
    
    //test cases 

    for _, tt := range tests{
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T){
            ts.get(t, tt.urlPath)
            //assertions
        })
    }
}
```

Note: I have wrapped mockAuthentication middleware with app.sessionManager.LoadAndSave middleware. This is essential to create a session in request context before assigning data to that session.

Hope this helps!